# How to store and retrieve HTML with correct encoding?

Tags: java, html, parsing, scala, encoding

*Please note this question evolved in time, because I found out gradually what would be the best approach to solve it. So now it is rarther a solution than a question :-).*

### The workflow

- I fetch html page
- I store it (file on disk)
- later I retrieve it to parse it
- just in case, I use TagSoup to fix the problems
- I parse the data as HTML

Please note I am talking about html page, so the encoding info is present in header (in meta tag).

Each step is the problem, because at any of them I could make mistake. So the question is how to fetch data, store it, retrieve it and finally parse it (correctly -- i.e. preserving encoding at each step)?

Comment: You may want to try the [getContentEncoding()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentEncoding()), and try to preserve the value in the file (probably, in the xml header tag) or use the [writeTo(..)](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream)) to directly write to the file, as it would avoid the encoding/decoding the content goes through when you use a reader on top of a stream.

Comment: The data has already such header -- it is normal html file. I guess the data come in byte form, and then they are interpreted as characters. I found already some discussion about it at Jakarta HttpClient page but this is not usable with Apache HttpClient (and it is hard to use google because those two are constantly mixed).

Comment: I think the correct strategy depends on the reason you're storing and re-reading the web page to begin with. If you're acting as a proxy the safest thing is to write and read uninterpreted byte streams, but I get the impression that's not what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can elaborate?

Comment: Honestly, it is odd that with purpose the way you store the data changes. In my case it is caching the data (live data has expire time), not proxy. I put it this way -- I need to store the data in such way, that simple test -- using the browser -- would give the exactly the same output as loading online page. Yet another way, my data and those stored with web browser "save page (html only)" should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Saving

I figured out it will be safer to save and load data as binary, despite the fact it is text. This way I avoid problem with encoding -- so except for parser I work only with Array[Byte].

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
  .writeByteArrayToFile(new File(filename),content)
```

### Retrieving & parsing

[G_H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630136/g-h) pointed out the JSoup library has the ability of detecting encoding by itself -- all one has to do is **NOT** to pass encoding info.

```
val data = org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
             .readFileToByteArray(new File(filename))
val doc = org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(new java.io
             .ByteArrayInputStream(data), null,"");
```

### Fetching

```
var content : Array[Byte] = null
val client = new org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient();
val httpget = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet(url);

try {
  val response = client.execute(httpget);
  val entity = response.getEntity()
  content = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity)

}
finally {
  client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

*Many thanks to [G_H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630136/g-h), JSoup was a turning point.*